# GitHub has error "ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref"

Tags: github

I am begiiner in java programming. When I create a Docker image via GitHub using actions to place it in the DockerHub repository, I encounter an error:

```
 > [2/2] COPY ./target/javarush_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./javarush_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     FROM openjdk:17
   2 | >>> COPY ./target/javarush_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./javarush_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
   3 |     ENV PORT=8080
   4 |     EXPOSE 8080
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref wqahreu2niiz97vfv6dg67edj::9cyyn3ncs2g8rctig8x30nu2q: failed to walk /tmp/buildkit-mount3384365397/target: lstat /tmp/buildkit-mount3384365397/target: no such file or directory
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref wqahreu2niiz97vfv6dg67edj::9cyyn3ncs2g8rctig8x30nu2q: failed to walk /tmp/buildkit-mount3384365397/target: lstat /tmp/buildkit-mount3384365397/target: no such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?
Yaml configuration:

```
steps:
      - 
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
        with:
          driver-opts: image=moby/buildkit:v0.11.0
      -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: catfindus/javarus-server:latest
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17
COPY ./target/javarush_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./javarush_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java","-jar","javarush_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I have tried different versions of the yaml file but the error remains